# React Native .then seems to be running out of order

Tags: javascript, react-native

I currently have the following method in a react native class, however I think this would apply to JS in general but I might be wrong:

```
  dbGetTemplateOptions = () => {
    let dataArray = [];
    let subcategories = this.state.subcategories;

    subcategories.forEach(item => {
      let getSubValues = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(item);
      })
      getSubValues.then((item) => this.dbGetValues(item.subCatId))
      getSubValues.then((value) => console.log(2))
    });
  }
```

According to my limited js knowledge of promises, in the above I'm resolving a promise and running getSubValues.then() which would mean that each of the .then methods run AFTER the method returns.

In the above code I call the method `dbGetValues(item.subCatId)`
Which is this:

```
  async dbGetValues(subCatId) {
    let subValues = [];
    let result = await db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'SELECT * FROM dr_template_relational '
        + ' INNER JOIN  dr_report_categorie_values on dr_report_categorie_values.id = dr_template_relational.value_id'
        + ' WHERE dr_template_relational.subcategory_id = ' + subCatId + ' AND dr_template_relational.template_id = ' + this.state.currentTemplateId,
        [],
      (trans, result) => {
        const sqLiteResults = result.rows._array;

        sqLiteResults.forEach(el => {
          subValues.push({ subCategoryId: subCatId, values: el.value_id, name: el.name, narrative: el.narrative });
        })
      });
    },
    (err) => console.error(err),
    () => {
      console.log(1);
      return subValues;
    }
  );
  return result;
  }
```

Notice my console.log(2) is after the then which is calling the method.
Inside the method also notice I have console.log(1).  I would expect these to run in order since I'm waiting for it to finish before the next then runs.  I realize I'm incorrect because the console.log is actually.

```
2
2
1
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  dbGetTemplateOptions = () => {
    let dataArray = [];
    let subcategories = this.state.subcategories;

    subcategories.forEach(item => {
      let getSubValues = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(item);
      })
      getSubValues.then((item) => this.dbGetValues(item.subCatId))
      getSubValues.then((value) => console.log(2))
    });
  }
```

You're resolving the promise before actually calling the asynchronous `dbGetValues` function. This is why the `then` triggers before the callbacks of `dbGetValues` do.

It's hard to know what changes to make without more context of what you're tying to do, but I think you might actually want something like:

```
  dbGetTemplateOptions = () => {
    let dataArray = [];
    let subcategories = this.state.subcategories;

    subcategories.forEach(item => {
      let getSubValues = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const result = await this.dbGetValues(item.subCatId)
        resolve(result);
      })
      getSubValues.then((value) => console.log(2))
    });
  }
```

Or to try to simplify even more:

```
  dbGetTemplateOptions = () => {
    let dataArray = [];
    let subcategories = this.state.subcategories;

    subcategories.forEach(async (item) => {
      const result = await this.dbGetValues(item.subCatId)
      // Do something with result here
      console.log(2)
    });
  }
```

Obviously this is based on assumptions of what you're doing